# Docker: exit with custom exit codes

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

I have below Docker cmd:

```
docker run -it -p 27017:27017 -v /Users/john/db/:/data/db --name k1 mongo
```

When I run above command, I want to precheck whether "/Users/john/db/" folder path already exists or not. If it does not exist, then I want to throw a custom exit code and stop the container from starting.

How to do this?

If I write an entrypoint script which will run before container starts, how would I access -v arguments? means this "/Users/john/db/" in entrypoint bash/python script?

Comment: I do not know about the custom exit  code, but I believe if you use `--mount type=bind,source=/Users/john/db,target=/data/db,readonly=false` then it will not start the container if `/Users/john/db` does not exist.

Comment: In general, your entrypoint script can not access the `-v` arguments.  It is possible, but should be considered a kludge.  Do not do it.